# get all assigned variables in a template using Blade

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

as I said in the title, I would like to get all assigned variables in a template using Blade with laravel 5.1

Example :

**Controller :**

```
class Ctrl extends Controller
{
  public function index() {
    $title = "i'm a title";
    $name = "i'm a name";
    return view('myview', compact('title', 'name'));
  }
}
```

**Template : myview.blade.php**

```
@getVars()
```

**Service provider :**

```
class getVarsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::directive('getVars', function() {
        // MUST return array('title' => "i'm a title", "name" => "i'm a name");
        return "all vars"; // <---- 
    });
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would calling get_defined_vars() work for you?